# My Ag-grid display is getting messed up when I scroll

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid display with about 1000 rows and 3 columns ... initially the display looks fine ... but as I scroll, somewhere around the 150th column.. my grid display gets messed up .. I stop seeing the border, scroll bar, header of the grid and left and right columns disappear ... below is an image of what I see. if I scroll further down, I will stop seeing the left and right columns and the header completely..

[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.. I don't even know where to look.
(Note: please ignore the black lines in the left column. I had to cover the text before I can post the image here.)

thank you
Vij

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when i used Internet Explorer.
I'm not so sure, that in your case it is the same, but my problem was solved with the lagging.

When you initialize your ag-gird add this to it:

`suppressScrollLag: true`

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One other option, even though it's not the most elegant one, is to increase the number of rows that get rendered outside the viewable content:

```
gridOptions.rowBuffer = 100;
```

The default is set to 20 rows.